# Using Bing API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bing, bing-api

How do we use the Bing API in C#? I have to pass a query to the Bing API and then get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download bing dlls from microsoft site and add those dlls . Then only we can able to use bing service.

Comment: Hello, any links for where these dlls can be downloaded?

Answer (score 5):

```
BingService.BingService service = new BingService.BingService();

        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        // use your Bing AppID
        request.AppId = ""; /* Your App ID */
        request.Query = "rose"; // your search query

        // I want to search only web
        request.Sources = new SourceType[]
        {
            SourceType.Image 
        };

        SearchResponse response = service.Search(request);

        foreach (ImageResult result in response.Image.Results)
        {

            //lstBxImages.Items.Add("<a href="+result.Url + '"'+"></a>" + result.Title);
            imgliteral.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<img src=" + result.MediaUrl + " width=100
```

Comment: what are the things i need to runn this code, and where do i get them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something will help you a lot 
https://github.com/insatmc/BingMapHelper

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to above there is a full documentation of te API given by BING in a PDF.

[Here is a Basic Details Version](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

hii..

Add a bing reference to web references in an application and use search.wsdl